# Change all author links in Blog roll

Tags: posts, functions, loop, post-meta, author

I want all the author links on my blog page to go to a specific url ("/about") instead of the individual author pages.

I know this can be done easily with JavaScript, but is there way to do it in functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try:

```
function wpse_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ){
    return 'http://example.com/';
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse_author_link', 20, 3 );
```